# Why are algebraic equations sometimes displayed as inverses instead of solving for the variable in question?

Tags: terminology, inverse, inverse-function

As the title suggests, why are some algebraic equations displayed as inverses instead of equalling the direct variable we're trying to solve?

For example, consider the d-spacing formulas used in crystallography where the variable of interest is d.

[image]

Why not just make all the equations equal to d not 1/d^2? If I want to use the equations I have to rearrange them anyway. is there a visual aspect to the equations I'm not seeing? I've seen a lot of other equations be put in inverse form too but I'm not too sure what the benefit is.

Comment: I have the impression that the author might have wanted to emphasize that all these cases expressed for 1/d^2 correspond to quadratic forms in the Miller indices h,k,l.

Comment: Maybe $1/d^2$ has some physical meaning in crystallography?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the expressions for $1/d^2$ are overall simpler than for $d^2$. While the expressions for $d^2$ would be no different in complexity in the first, fourth, and seventh cases, they would be more complex in the other four cases: either introducing double-decker fractions or longer polynomial expressions if  the numerators and denominators are multiplied up to clear the extra layer of fractions.

Comment: Really? I don't see how they're simpler... why not just leave it as d instead of d^2 or 1/d^2?

Comment: $$\frac1a=\frac1b+\frac1c$$ takes fewer lines than $$a=\dfrac1{\dfrac1b+\dfrac1c}.$$ Also, there is nothing to stop you putting a square-root sign over the whole expression, if you so wish. Similarly, you could write Pythagoras' theorem as $c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$  instead of $c^2=a^2+b^2$ (etc.).

Comment: Great point, I see what you mean now, thanks! :)